# CORS missing allow origin problem in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors, cross-domain

I am working with react js, node and axios on a small api request project. I have a problem with an api request. The error is CORS missing allow origin. the cross-origin request is blocked, because the CORS is missing. I tried to look at the online documentation but I haven't solved it. Thank you.

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Its because 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present in the response.

Try to add
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Header in the node api response and It should work fine